# How to create multiple tuples from single tuple in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have column like '5060-5070' in pig and I want to write a udf to return tuples as below:

col1 and col2 will be same in all the tuples.

col1,col2,5060,....

col1,col2,5061,..

col1,col2,5062,..

or if there is any alternative (instead of using udf) to create multiple tuples from single tuple .

Comment: UDF is your only option

Comment: so can you help me writing that??

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_user_defined_functions.htm .
Check this link as a start to writing UDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should create a UDF that returns Databag. Databag can contain any number of tuples. Then use flatten to expand this databag. Use BagFactory to create DataBag, use TupleFactory to create a tuple and add it inside it.

Comment: okay..but I want to do some processing on columns. how can i use the columns inside udf??

Comment: any UDF recieves a tuple that it can process. For example if you do smth like foreach A generate yourNiceUDF(col1, col2); you will recieve a Tuple conaining value of col1 at 0 index (meaning you can get it using tuple.get(0);) and value of col2 at index 1

Comment: If you are writing a UDF for the first time, good to look at smth simple like https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/MilliSecondsBetween.java as an example

Comment: thanks... I m done with udf, and its running fine . thanks for your help